# How to create an eclipse org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder at WorkspaceLevel?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to create some upper levels (group of `IFolder`) for my Eclipse project which will have some configurations file.

My question is: Would it be possible to create an `IProject` inside an `IFolder` or `IProject` inside an `IProject` at workspace root level?

One solution is to  customize `IFolder` or `IProject` source code.

Any better solution would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Projects can only be created at the workspace level. They cannot be nested.

Folders can only be created within projects or another folder, they cannot be at the workspace level.

Changing the `IFolder` or `IProject` implementation is a non-starter. These assumptions are fundamental to the workspace design and would be extremely hard to change.